# Get posts of a custom post type from another wordpress on another server?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I got this two wordpress installations on two different servers.

1. external site; on this I got a custom post type (faq), I use this to store all my faq posts, both for external and internal use.
2. internal site; on this I want to load in the custom post type from site no. 1 so I don't have to double post the content.

I've used `<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');    ?>` before but this time they dont share the same $_SERVER.

Comment: you'll have to set up a DB connection to the other server (a security risk, unless you use an SSH tunnel)

Comment: Or.. You could use `REST API` and have a cron job looking every hour or something, and insert posts into your DB, but then you need to add `'show_in_rest' => true,` on the registration of the post type on site 1

Comment: @Stender REST API!! thats it! Thanks man, 
now I know what to do the rest of the week :)

Comment: you could actually make site 1 push it to site 2 with rest as well - that way you won't need to wait for the CRON job to execute - You could hook in on your CPT save transitions on site 1. something like : https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/rest-api-create-delete-posts.html#create_post - Both ways are valid. one waits for CRON, the other takes longer to save.